# How can I run a 7.2VDC battery-powered drill off a 220VAC wall socket with limited part availability?

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc

I have a battery drill, but the battery is useless, so I want to power direct from the outlet.

I need convert 220VAC to **7.2VDC @ 4A**.

I can't use a transformer because the high output current, it will raise a lot the size and the price of the solution, that should be lower than a new battery.

I don't want to design my own switching power supply because where I live its not so easy to get the ICs and inductors.

What could be the best way to convert it with a small and cheap solution?

*edit:* I'm located in Brazil.

Comment: Well, you've ruled out the two actual solutions! Are you not better off buying a cheap new mains drill, which will have considerably higher power motor?

Comment: @pjc50 No I don't want to buy I new one, this drill is already very powerfull and expensive, and don't want to lose it.

Comment: So buy a new battery? I mean, how much does one cost?

Comment: _Transformers_ do not convert AC to DC, you're thinking of rectifiers. Buy a switch-mode PSU, or charge up a 6v motorcycle battery and wire it to that, it will have a lot more juice than the drill's battery. I use 12v/14v drills with old car batteries.

Comment: @StephenCollings I want to power from AC, an outlet. Battery its not an option.

Comment: The best way is hardly ever the cheapest way if you are ruling out the two most obvious solutions. Buy a mains powered drill or a replacement battery.

Comment: @JohnU I know that the Transformer don't convert AC to DC, but it lower the tension to transform AC to DC. I could be easy to answer to just put a transformer and a rectifier, but this is what I don't want.

Comment: @Andyaka I will repeat, buy a new drill or a new battery is not an option. I just want a soultion to transform 220VAC to 7.2VDC @ 4A without a transformer and without having to design a switching power supply.

Comment: A battery drill won't have safe levels of insulation because it doesn't need to. Without using a transformer I can't think of a solution that would be safe.

Comment: Are you SURE the motor draws just 4A? That seems like a nice average figure, but I'd expect a much higher peak current draw.

Comment: You say in comments to answers that you can't get parts cheaply where you live. However, you haven't filled in your location in your profile. Remember, your profile information is for us, not for you. Filling in all fields is a courtesy to those you seek help from. Others more familiar with electronics suppliers in your area, whatever that is, might be able to suggest alternatives you are not aware of. I find it hard to believe that 7.5 V power supplies aren't available in your area, since they are available all over the world.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Its available yes, but its not cheapest as is in Digikey. And not worth the price for this solution.

Comment: No, your question was downvoted for good reason.  You asked a impossible/unrealistic question, but then refused to listen to answers that told you that.  I gave you some slack initially, but when you became stubborn and uncooperative I and 3 others (so far) downvoted your question.  It is not adding anything useful to this site and it appears you are learning nothing from it.

Comment: If I have made a  impossible/unrealistic question you should ask to remove the question instead making trouble. Its obvious that I will try to hear the best answer for my question. I just want to hear a good answer that fit my question. And the only question that had fitted for my question, was downvoted even fitted every requirement of the question for prank! I don't care if I had to put a fan on it, it will works, something that no one had answered!

Comment: The thing is this... You may think it's a good answer but the guys here (including me) think it's a bad answer and we're telling you but you are not listening to the experts. Good luck, I hope you can get something to work.

Answer (score 9):

Let's start with all your options, so you can see why you really, really want a transformer.

You want to convert a high voltage to a low voltage. You can do that with

1. a linear power supply, or
2. a switching power supply.

A linear supply at the voltages you're talking about would be horribly inefficient. 220 VAC rectified gives ~310 VDC. 7.2/310 = 2.3% efficiency. You'll be consuming 28.8 watts of power, and dumping 1200 watts to a heatsink. A heatsink, fan, and semiconductor device able to handle that will cost at least $200, and occupy roughly a 20 cm (8 in) cube.

Switching supply is much more practical, which is why they're used in almost every charger of anything you're likely to come across. Then it's a question of what topology you want. The only switching topology that doesn't require inductors or transformers is a [charge pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_pump). To do a 30:1 buck, you'll need ~30 capacitors, transistors, and drive circuits. *Very* complex, lots of parts, lots to go wrong. So let's stick to solutions that involve magnetics, and find a way to get you the parts you want.

There are a couple unisolated topologies you could use. You could do a straight [buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter), but a 30:1 buck ratio might be problematic. Also, the failure mode on a buck converter is bad: if the transistor shorts, the full input voltage goes to the output, and bam, no more drill.

I use [SEPIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEPIC_converter) converters often for this kind of thing. More parts, but they fail more safely. In fact, I've built some recently in this exact power range. Parts cost to do it, with parts on hand already tested, and quantity discounts, was about $150. But I'd never, **ever** use that to power something that a human being was holding.

As others rightly point out, you really want a transformer, which will fail even more safely than the SEPIC. The available short-circuit current will be limited by the energy that can get through the core, and if a transistor shorts, your load is safe. And remember, this is something that's **in your hand**. Safety is your top priority.

So now you need a transformer, and 1-4 switches, depending on your topology, and isolated feedback or drive circuits, and your cost probably now exceeds the $150 I mentioned above for the SEPIC.

I'd just buy one of these for $20:
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/WSU075-4000/237-1627-ND/3105442

It's a 7.5V supply, but I'd be shocked (ha...) if your drill wouldn't handle that. Odds are that your 7.2V battery is only 7.2V nominal, not 7.2V all the time. I'd suspect its charger's output voltage was 7.5V. I make no guarantees. But if it was my drill, I'd try it.

Comment: I was also thinking along the lines of a wall-wart but I do wonder if it is the case that the drill battery can, and sometimes must, supply much more than 4A to the drill motor.

Comment: As I said where I live its not so cheap and easy to get this things. So if I buy from Digikey I will pay just for shipping $40, plus taxes and everything else that reach 60% of the price of the product plus taxes, so probably I will pay  something near $100 to buy it. And if I buy a similar power supply here, I will pay the same $100. I wasn't plan to spend so much money.

Comment: How much did the drill cost?

Comment: Something like $200

Comment: So what parts CAN you get? I mean, if you can't order from Digikey without it being prohibitively expensive, how do you propose to build anything at all?

Comment: Looks like you got hit by the Phantom Downvoter too. Someone here can't seem to separate the quality of answers from how much they match what they wanted to hear.

Comment: @OlinLathrop If you read the comments you will understand that the answer is not filling the requisites of the question and its not a good answer for the question. And even its the most wonderful answer and good writed, if its not right why should someone upvote it?

Comment: This solution of using a ready made power supply may seem to be a really cool way to go but it is not likely to be suitable. The types of batteries used in power tools are designed to deliver huge surge currents that may be 10X or more of the nominal rating of the battery. Most AC->DC power supplies, especially the cheapest ones, cannot even begin to deliver the sustained surge currents that would be required for suitable operation of the power tool. Performance of such setup would be similar to what you get out of a battery that has reached its end of life. It will looked (continued)...

Comment: (continued from above)...charged with no load on it but will fall apart when the drill is asked to deliver any amount of torque at all. This of course happens because the end of life battery has had its internal impedance go way up.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, that's precisely what I was thinking when I commented above.  Thanks for confirming that suspicion.

Comment: A good point. But that means we need clearer specs.

Comment: @Butzke: The answer may not be exactly according to your specs, but the problem is your specs are unrealistic.  Someone telling you that is a good answer.  The problem seems to be it's not what you want to hear, but that doesn't make the answer bad.  All things aren't possible just because you can ask about them.  You would be better off if you listened to what people are telling you instead of filtering out anything you wish weren't true.  The answer you accepted is closer to what you wanted to hear, but it's still a bad/unworkable idea.  Go try it.  Maybe you'll learn that way.

Answer (score 7):

You do NOT want to try to power the drill with circuity that is attached direct to the AC powerline without the isolation that a transformer provides. Such method of powering the tool will likely be a serious safety hazard as the tool design is sure to not be designed with the proper double insulated characteristics that a proper mains attached tool would have.

If you proceed forward with such design without the proper isolation you are likely to suffer serious injury or electrocution.

Another piece of advice - Any properly designed and isolated power supply that you may be able to come up with is surely going to cost you more than a new battery would.

Answer (score 6):

At 30 Watts, a transformer is the only realistic way to get power from the power line accross a isolation barrier.  And yes, you need that isolation.  It is possible to have a power supply that makes 7.2 VDC from 220 VAC without isolation, but that would be very dangerous, especially considering how a drill would be used.

You have some conflicting specs.  This is apparently a one-off, yet you want it to be cheap.  You seem to be asking for a design that meets certain criteria, but yet you don't want to buy ICs and and inductors.  These requirements are conflicting at best.  Not everything is possible just because you can write a spec for it.

For a one-off like this, I'd get a off the shelf power supply.  A line-connected power supply is not a beginner project for several reasons.  A screwup can easily kill you, you'll probably fry some parts experimening with high voltage (over 300 V peak) and 30 Watts, and it will take a lot of time to tweak once you do get a reasonable topology.  In the end there will still be a transformer in there anyway.

A appropriate power supply should only cost a few 10s of $.  The common power supply voltage of 7.5 V should be good enough.  Even if not, many "7.5 V" power supplies can be adjusted down to 7.2 V.

Comment: There's a fair leeway too - a nominal 7.2v drill battery will be much higher voltage when fully charged, the motor will probably happily tolerate 10v, and 5v at the low end although lower voltage will mean higher current in the motor which may burn it out - but it does mean a cheap ATX PSU could provide the power.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: It would be useful to explain what exactly you think is incorrect, misleading, badly written, etc.  Silent downvotes do the site a disservice.

Comment: @JohnU Good idea!

Answer (score 5):

What the heck, I'll throw my comment in as an answer as I know it works.

As pointed out in the comments above, 4A is a nominal current, under load the drill will draw a lot more and probably give a cheap SMPS a bad time (or give a poor drilling experience).

7.2v is also a nominal value, the battery voltage will vary a fair bit so we have some leeway here.

Find an old 6v battery (EG moped / motorbike, UPS, etc.) and a charger (a 4A rated one preferably, depending on how long you need to drill for). I am assuming you have both of these things in Brazil and they are not unobtainium that you have to specially import.

Charge the battery, connect the drill battery input terminals to it using a length of wire (minimum 10A capable, automotive or speaker wire, or mains flex will work), use the drill. Use the charger to charge the battery.

I use this method with a couple of 12v / 14v drills that had dead batteries, and an old car battery (or the battery in my car) and it works great.

Car batteries (even ones that can't start a car anymore) can provide a lot more current than your old drill battery, you might want to put a 10A automotive fuse in the line.

Answer (score 2):

You can just take a look at products like http://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-513037054-fonte-de-75v-500ma-1a-2a-3a-4a-plug-p4-bivolt-_JM that will cost lower than $10.

Comment: That's not even close to the required current.

Comment: 4A ? It's what the question asked...

Comment: It clearly says "500 mA".  Then there is a bunch of stuff in a language I can't read.  There is a single price listed, so it doesn't seem this supply comes in different versions.

Comment: @woliveirajr You are right, its wrote 7.5V @ 4A

Comment: @OlinLathrop It's just how one would advertise on "Mercado Livre" (think of eBay): someone searching for 7.5v, 500mA would also find this result... although the description states: "* Corrente Máxima: 4 A" -> maximum current: 4 A... I just posted this Brazilian site because the OP updated his profile and said he is from Brazil.

Comment: OK, although it would have been helpful to say so in your question.  I just tried to undo my downvote but the system won't let me without the question getting edited.

Comment: @OlinLathrop no problem at all :)

Answer (score -5):

You could use an old notebook power supply, so you don't need to buy anything new. And you will be isolating AC from DC.

This power supply gives you something nearest 19V @ 4A normally, and use a adjustable tension regulator in the output to set the tension that you want.

You can use a [LM338](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm138.pdf) as Adjustable Regulator, it can drive until 5A.

So you only need to buy a tension regulator, some resistor and capacitors, that could be easily found in almost every electronics shop, and will be very cheap compared of the other answers.

This circuit with the regulator could be put inside the drill in place of the battery.

**So this solution will be cheap and small.**

Comment: A linear regulator dropping 19V to 7.2V at 4.5A will dissipate about 53 watts - have you factored the cost of the heat-sink in to your proposal?

Comment: LM338 have Metal Can Package and its easily to screw in some dissipator. This package can support 50W and can drive the 5A until 75°C. And (19 - 7,2) * 4 = 47,2W, then it is viable.

Comment: This is a bad idea due to the high power that will be dissipated in the linear regulator.  7.5 V power supplies are cheap and available too.  There is no need to get one with a inconvenient voltage and then regulate it down, *especially* when it is only 40% efficient and dissipates over 45 W of heat.

Comment: You'll need voltage protection devices if the input supply gets disconnected. The motor will keep turning producing about 7V at top speed and this will damage the LM138 which can only take -0.3V input to output. Ditto on the output - you'll need protection diodes for back emfs from the motor. I guess commutation can create some serious spikes too - the LM138 is rated at max 40V. TO-3 can will be nearly 50ºC warmer inside at 50W. Max internal temp is 150ºC therefore no more 100ºC on surface of heat-sink - that needs a HS that is below 1.4 ºC/watt (quite big). Install a fan!

Comment: @Andyaka Let the mechanical engineers worry about such nonsense!!!

Comment: I doubt that the required heatsink will meet the OP's statement of "small".

Comment: What a strange place in the world the OP lives that he can get linear regulators but not switching regulators...

Comment: @Butzke: No phantom at all.  There are a number of comments explaining why this is a bad answer.

Comment: A 1.4C/W sink would be on the order of 2" x 2" x 2", with a fan. Whether that's bigger than the OP wants, I don't know. Again we lack clear specs.